# iOS8 Segmented Control Dragging Long Press

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

Our app worked fine in iOS7. Since iOS8 we have some strange behaviour appearing. We have a scrollview which contains a segmented control. You can drag the time bar across and then tap on an hour choice for the time of day.

What's happening now is the segmented control appears to be allowing long presses and drags and then highlighting each segment with a grey border. If you disable touches in IB on the segmented control the scrollview works fine (as expected).

If you click and drag extremely quickly you can still get the scroll view to scroll. But ideally we want the segmented control just to work in its original way and not capture drags/swipes

The link below shows a video with the issue in a simulator, it's the same on a device as well

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IQu00ed_fU

Comment: Have you tried a scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing:

```
- (BOOL) touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return YES;
}
```

On the UIScrollView that the Segmented Control was placed within solved the problem.